# How come "println" without being enclosed in a method, allowed inside a scala class?

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala and in Scala I found that one can write println directly inside a class despite it not being a variable or method, how is this possible?

Even if println is a method then why aren't we defining it in the class as required generally for methods? Why despite being a method it is not allowed directly in Java class but allowed in Scala?

E.g.

```
class Hero {  
  println("running fine...")  // Why is this println allowed in scala when its not inside a function?
}  

object MainObject{  
  def main(args: Array[String]){  
     new Hero()  
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, it runs inside the Class constructor. Any code inside the Class besides the variable and function declarations is constructor's code.

Answer (score 4):

You can write any statement directly inside a class and it will be run whenever the class is instantiated.

Comment: I know that but in any other object oriented language like Java its not allowed. A class is only supposed to have variables and methods but in Scala its an exception so I wanted to know the reason.

Answer (score 2):

When you open up an editor and start typing code, you will find, that some things are already available and some need to be imported. So all of these things which are available without importing are present in the scala.Predef package.

`println` is one of the methods made available by the scala compiler in the scala.Predef package.

```
def println() = Console.println()
```

If you check the scala docs, println method internally calls the Console object to print the contents on the screen.

Comment: "all of these things which are available without importing are present in the scala.Predef package" Not all: `java.lang._` and `scala._` are imported too.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov thanks for mentioning that. I missed out on that

Answer (score 0):

> I'm new to Scala and in Scala I found that one can write println directly inside a class despite it not being a variable or method, how is this possible?

You are wrong: `println` *is* a method, that's why this is possible. [Here is the documentation for `scala.Predef.println`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html#println(x:Any):Unit).

Comment: Even if println is a method then why aren't we defining it in the class as required for other methods? Why despite being a method it is not allowed directly in Java class but allowed in Scala?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. We don't need to define it, because it is already defined for us, in `scala.Predef`, just like many other methods. This concept of methods that are already defined is called a "library" and it exists in many other languages as well.